# Rails charachter encoding problem view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, character-encoding

The character encoding starts to irritate me.
It took me a while to get everything from the DB in the right encoding on the screen, but with help from the i18n helper, this worked out.
Now I only have one more problem: saving text...
If i add some letters with accents (eg é ç ...) in a text field and want to save it, already in my controller it show as some exotic combination of characters.
Could someone tell me why this is and how I can fix this.
Everything is in UTF-8 btw

Thanks!

//Edit:
When I save the form, this is my log output

```
Parameters: {"free_text"=>"test 1 2 Ã©",
```

And everything is capable of UTF-8...

Answer (score 0):

Can you illustrate your output?

Let me guess your situation.

Supposed that you log those characters in controller in log/development.log or production.log.

If you view that log in terminal, you should ensure your terminal is capable to show UTF-8, with appropriate font.  Also, your shell is capable to show UTF-8 and so do your the text viewer.

Comment: I've added some info in my start post.